# DMN Decision Table Output

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I am new to decision table so please forgive me if I asked a very basic question. I am working on an angular web app that uses decision table.

Could we change the table header 'Output' to something else?

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot find any such label neither in the HTML nor in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: 
It cannot be done through CSS. therefore following is my solution.

Inspect the code that either the dmn table is using modeling module or some other bpmn table features. In my case, it is using modeling. I override the following module by inheriting from it, to make the Input header cell dynamic and output fixed or change the label as well.

https://github.com/bpmn-io/dmn-js/blob/31803afe1bdccdc350da73293a75e2cbf3f14932/lib/table/features/modeling/Modeling.js